# bash script to create folder names out of a portion of a filename

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm new to bash, and coding. I have a list of files:

```
test-T01___2022.txt
test-T01__2021.txt
test-T01_NONE.txt
test-T02___2022.txt
test-T02__2021.txt
test-T02_NONE.txt
test-T03___2022.txt
test-T03__2021.txt
test-T03_NONE.txt
```

I'm trying to write a script to create folders T01 (containing *T01 files), T02 (containing all files with T02), etc. I'm trying with wildcards and regexps and something similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618663/creating-a-folder-based-on-a-portion-of-a-file-name) but having some trouble. I appreciate some help.

Many thanks!

Comment: The proposed duplicate describes how to remove prefixes and suffixes from strings, which is what you want to do I think.

Comment: @rghome indeed, I want to create folders from T0i for i belonging to [0-9]

Comment: Just remove the prefix test- and the suffix _*.

Comment: just iterate it :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the bash prefix and suffix removal operations. See the link in the comments for more details.

For example:

```
files=...
for file in $files
do
    a=${file#test-}
    dir=${a%%_*}
    mkdir "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```